# "Not defined" variable (table_count) but I did define it

Tags: python

```
def is_int(val):
    if type(val) == int:
        return True
    else:
        if val.is_integer():
            return True
        else:
            return False
mult_tble = float(input("Which multiplication table would you like?: "))
if is_int(mult_tble):
    mult_tble = int(mult_tble)
    print(mult_tble)
else:
    print(mult_tble)
def tble():
    table_count = float(input("How high do you want to go?: ")) + 1
    return table_count
tble()
if is_int(table_count):
    table_count = int(table_count)
    print(table_count)
else:
    print("That is not an integer")
    tble()
print("Here's your table:")
for i in range(1, table_count):
    print(i, " x " + str(mult_tble) + " =", i * mult_tble)`
```

The error message when I run is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/embleton/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/game.py", 
line 20, in <module>
if is_int(table_count):
NameError: name 'table_count' is not defined
```

I thought that I defined `table_count` in my `tble()` function, but I guess not.
Please help. I'm a noobie at python and I can't figure this out.

Comment: you defined it only locally; try `table_count = tble()` in line 19

Comment: exactly, you defined it "inside" a function, and you're trying to access it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to take the return value of `tble()`.

Try again like this-

```
def tble():
    table_count = float(input("How high do you want to go?: ")) + 1
    return table_count
table_count = tble()
if is_int(table_count):
    table_count = int(table_count)
    print(table_count)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! I'm a beginner programming in python, and it means a lot to me that other people can help me out with even the simplest of tasks. So thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Snoopy425 If that solved your problem, please accept it, it might help others also. Glad to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`table_count` scope has ended in `def tble()`. So it errors out saying it is not defined.

So assign the return of `tble()` to `table_count` and use it further like below:

```
table_count = tble()
if is_int(table_count):
    table_count = int(table_count)
    print(table_count)
```